# Simultaneous DTI, structural MRI and 1H-MRS - Are there any examples of this?

Tags: neuroimaging

I have been reading about recent articles relating to treatment resistant schizophrenia, and apparently there are a lack of studies using multimodal imaging. Initially I just thought that would be suggesting carrying out different techniques on the same sample, however some other papers I have read talk about actually recording the data simultaneously (e.g. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2900394/). This has been a bit tricky to read into further as a lot of the papers I've read are a bit unclear as to whether they're actually recording the data simultaneously or just on the same subject across the span of a study.

http://cobre.mrn.org/phase1/projects/project4.html
This is the thing that particularly interested me, the possibility of carrying out a structural MRI, DTI and 1H-MRS simultaneously. However they don't really elucidate how they'll go about this.

I am not very knowledgeable about imaging techniques (this is probably obvious), but I'm really intrigued by this and wondered if anyone could elaborate on how they record MRI, DTI and 1H-MRS data in one session and if it would be a lot harder to interpret. Is a particular standard of machine required as well?